# JIRA export to Excel: manipulation of the original estimate date field

Tags: excel, jira

**Issue**: i export my data from JIRA into Excel and want to review the original estimates for each task that was entered in JIRA. JIRA exports this field as a date and these numbers appear in excel as the total number of hours.

[example values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiWhI.png)

Because these fields are formatted as dates i am not able to simply divide these numbers by 8 to get the number of work days required.

**advice requested**: any ideas on how i can extract/copy these values from the cells in excel to another set of cells and divide by 8? perhaps the answer is not doing this and dividing by 8 - if so i'm all ears!

thanks

Comment: Something along the lines of `=INT((E2-DATE(1900;1;1))*24)` should give you total hours as integers (maybe the start date needs tweaking). From there on normal division should work. The correct conversion formula depends on your actual input (the actual date/time values stored) so could you maybe link to a small csv/xls with those sample values from the screenshot?

Comment: exactly its the input value that is throwing me for a loop @Max3x Here is a copy of the xls data. hang on new this attaching files here...

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101925586/sample.xlsx

Comment: thanks for any eyes that were cast on this... i went with this as a solution: =TEXT(E2,"[H]") then divided by 8.